# Are references maintained when archiving and unarchiving using NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

Suppose I do the following:

```
CarObject *car1 = [CarObject new];
CarObject *car2 = [CarObject new];

NSArray *carObjectsList1 = @[car1, car2];
NSArray *carObjectsList2 = @[car1, car2];
```

Also suppose that the car objects implement the NSCoding protocol. Let's say I archive and 
unarchive:

```
//Archive
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:carObjectsList1 toFile:@"list1.dat"];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:carObjectsList2 toFile:@"list2.dat"];
//Unarchive
NSArray *unarchivedList1 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"list1.dat"];
NSArray *unarchivedList2 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"list2.dat"];
```

Then suppose I do this:

```
CarObject *car1 = unarchivedList1 objectAtIndex:0];
car1.isTireFlat = true;
```

Would doing this change the property of "Car1" in both arrays? Meaning, would the first car object of both arrays have a flat tire? Are the reference links still preserved? Does anyone know why the answer is as such (as in, how are they preserved/why are they not preserved?)

Edit:  I've edited my question to provide a more correct example.

Comment: I'd like to note that I did try this myself, but I got different results both times I tried it.  I might have done something wrong, though.

Comment: The line `[unarchivedList1 objectAtIndex:0] = nil;` doesn't do anything. What did you intend with that line?

Comment: Why don't you log the two unarchived arrays and see what the object pointers are. It's very unlikely that the two arrays will share the same two objects.

Comment: Thanks. I confirmed that they are not the same objects. Even though the two arrays share the same object, they write the same object to disk twice, in different file locations.

Comment: This question is very confused. As noted `[unarchivedList1 objectAtIndex:0] = nil` is invalid and meaningless. Beyond that, the arrays are immutable. Beyond **that**, take archiving out of the equation altogether and assume mutable arrays and sensible operations on those arrays: `[car1 removeObjectAtIndex:0]` would not affect `car2`. So, why would you imagine that operating on `unarchivedList1` would affect `unarchivedList2`?

Comment: Perhaps it was a bad example. I know that the NSArrays are immutable, but that does not mean the objects within them are immutable. If [unarchivedList1 objectAtIndex:0] returned Car1, and I modify a property of Car1, would [unarchivedList2 objectAtIndex:0]'s object also be modified?  That was the question I was trying to answer. The answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

If you archive two arrays that share the same object, you archive the that object twice. Then, when you unarchive those two arrays, you independently unarchive those arrays as if they were different objects.  References aren't maintained upon unarchiving since each unarchive creates new object instances by calling initWithCoder: in the NSCoding protocol.

Comment: References *within* an archive are preserved. So, if you archived two arrays that shared elements into a single archive and then unarchived that, you'd get two elements which shared elements. The specific elements would be different than the original two arrays, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `NSKeyedArchiver` can even cope with reference cycles.